# Need Help,There's no error but can't go to another form for this multi user form code(c#)

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, syntax-error

I'm new to coding,and i need help with the code. There's no error found,and the program is running . but can't go to another form either Supervisor or Cashier, and I also found this in my debug output: A first chance exception of type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred in System.Data.dll
errorSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904).

```
    SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\User\Desktop\Assignment_IOOP\Assignment_IOOP\LoginDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    public string UserType;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trydb();

    }

    private void trydb() {
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Logindata where username '" +Usertext.Text+ "' and password '" +Passtext.Text+"' ;", myCon);
            DataTable logicaldb = new DataTable();
            MyDataAdapter.Fill(logicaldb);
            int count = logicaldb.Rows.Count;
            if (count > 0)
            {

                UserType = logicaldb.Rows[0][4].ToString();

                if (UserType == "Supervisor")
                {
                    Manage_Product spv = new Manage_Product();
                    spv.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else if (UserType == "Cashier")
                {
                    Cashier csh = new Cashier();
                    csh.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unknown User Type");
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception a) {
            Console.Write("error" + a.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Which line is producing the error?

Comment: You should, at least, include in your question what you're trying to achieve. Also consider including a minimal, complete and verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You are missing `=` operators. Also, you should parameterize your queries, especially when dealing with passwords

Comment: And... you suppress the exception with your catch block. If it is program critical it's better to raise the exception otherwise you'll stumble onto these kind of problems.

Comment: Thank you for the tips,i'm new to coding and just recently using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is because you haven't open the connection before using it. First open the connection with the line "myCon.Open();" before using it in SqlDataAdapter and then use the '=' operator in the select query of the where clause. you have missed that too in your query.

Your code should be

```
private void trydb() {
    try
    {
       myCon.Open();
       SqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Logindata where username ='" +Usertext.Text+ "' and password ='" +Passtext.Text+"' ;", myCon);
        DataTable logicaldb = new DataTable();
        MyDataAdapter.Fill(logicaldb);
        //rest of your code here
    }
    catch
    {
      //exception code here
    }
   }
```

Comment: Thank you,now the problem is fixed :)